# calculating the sum total of the columns and display in footer when colum names are dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a DataTable whose data are retrieved from the database. I am trying to get sum of the values of each cells every column wise and display in the footer of the DataTable .

But the problem is, my retrieved column names are dynamic, they vary every time user gives different input. How can I get the sum of the each column when my column names are dynamic.

```
protected void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string from_date = srch_date.Text.ToString();
        string to_date = srch_to_date.Text.ToString();

        dt = new DAL_Reports().Rpt_Count_Transpose(from_date, to_date);
        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt_;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Comment: Don't do `catch (Exception ex) { }`. That's going to swallow all errors and you won't know they happened. At least log the error.

Comment: Clarify whether you want the sum total of all cells or the total of every  column in the footer

Comment: @Nkosi I want the sum total of every column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop all the columns and rows in the DataTable and show the results in the footer.

```
DataTable dt = new DAL_Reports().Rpt_Count_Transpose(from_date, to_date);

//create a array to store the total column values
int[] RowTotals = new int[dt.Columns.Count];

//loop all the rows in the datatable
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    //loop all the columns in the row
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        //add the values for each cell to the total
        RowTotals[i] += Convert.ToInt32(row[dt.Columns[i].ColumnName]);
    }
}

//loop all the columns again to set the values in the footer
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[i].Text = string.Format("{0:N2}", RowTotals[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the maximim column number, you can deal with it in the RowDataBound event of the GridView:

Declare an array of totals at the page class level:

```
int maxTotals = 10;
Decimal[] Totals = new Decimal[10];
```

Process data in RowDatBound event

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.HeaderRow)
  {
   //Initialize totals array
   for (int k=0; k<=maxTotals; k++)
     totals[k]=0;
  }
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
   //Collect totals from relevant cells
   DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
   for (int k=0; k<=maxTotals; k++)
      totals[k] += (Decimal)rowView[k];
  }
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.FooterRow)
  {
   //Show totals
   for (int k=0; k<=maxTotals; k++)
     e.Row.Cells[k].Text = String.Format("{0:c}",totals[k]);
  }
}
```

In case you don't know the column maximum number, you can always put a try/catch in the for loop and exit the loop in case of an ArrayOutOfBoundException